# What is a better way to write this regular expression?

Tags: regex, textmate

I am converting XML children into the element parameters and have a dirty regex script I used in Textmate. I know that dot (.) doesn't search for newlines, so this is how I got it to resolve.

Search

```
language="(.*)"
(.*)<education>(.*)(\n)?(.*)?(\n)?(.*)?(\n)?(.*)?</education>
(.*)<years>(.*)</years>
(.*)<grade>(.*)</grade>
```

Replace

```
grade="$13" language="$1" years="$11">
        <education>$3$4$5$6$7$8$9</education>
```

I know there's a better way to do this. Please help me build my regex skills further.

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags.

Comment: It would help if you could show a piece of the XML you have, and the XML you want it to be. I find it hard to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: How do I write "(.*)(\n)?(.*)?(\n)?(.*)?(\n)?(.*)?" and "$3$4$5$6$7$8$9" in such a way that I don't have to duplicate myself for every possible newline and returned value?

Comment: From a regex-perspective, replace `(.*)(\n)?(.*)?(\n)?(.*)?(\n)?(.*)?` with `[\s\S]*?`. But really, as already mentioned: don't parse xml with regex.

Comment: Thanks! I am converting this Word document to XML so I really can't parse it yet with ActionScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an xml parser, don't use regex to parse xml.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no other tags inside the `<education>` element, I would change that part to:

```
<education>([^<>]*)</education>
```

If possible, I would use the same technique everywhere else you're using `.*`. In the case of the `language` attribute, it would take this form:

```
language="([^"]*)"
```